# How many languages does Paul Erdős have publications in?

Tags: mathematicians, publishing, language

I was flicking through [these slides](https://users.monash.edu/%7Egfarr/research/slides/Brent-multiplication-Monash.pdf) by Prof. Richard Brent, wherein we have:

> Erdős (1955, in Hebrew) gave an upper bound M(n) = o(n<sup>2</sup>) as n → ∞. After some encouragement by Linnik and Vinogradov, he proved (1960, in Russian) that ... [asymptotic formula].  ([screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/zGVVcny/Screenshot-2022-06-03-at-13-09-48-Algorithms-for-the-Multiplication-Table-Problem-Brent-multiplicati.png))

If I'm interpreting this correctly, Erdős has publications in both Hebrew and Russian.  I've read some of his papers in English, and I'm guessing he'd have some in Hungarian too.  Hence...

**Question**: How many languages does Paul Erdős have publications in?

The references in the slides are are:

> P. Erdős, Some remarks on number theory, Riveon Lematematika 9 (1955), 45–48 (Hebrew).
>
> P. Erdős, An asymptotic inequality in the theory of numbers, Vestnik Leningrad Univ. 15, 13 (1960), 41–49 (Russian). For a correction, see MR603312 (82c:10053).

Comment: Why don't you look at the  list of his publications https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=erdos%2C+paul and count yourself?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Index of P. Erdös's papers](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/) he has at least 2 papers in each of the following languages:

- English
- French
- German
- Hebrew
- Hungarian
- Russian

It is said that he once wanted to publish a paper [in Kurdish](https://paulerdos.weebly.com/) but he wasn't able to do so because he could not find a Kurdish math journal...

Comment: Hm! No Italian or Portuguese? Or Esperanto!?!? :)